# How to Specify the location of the Exchange Logs for a eseutil Soft Recovery?

Tags: exchange-2003

I have restored the Exchange databases and logs with netbackup, but need to do a soft recovery.  This [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824126) says to use the following command:

```
eseutil /r r00 /i /d"c:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\Recovery Storage Group"
```

I restored the log files to a particular folder, how do I specify where the log files are?

Comment: Edited answer for a possible easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997761(EXCHG.65).aspx) article : ESEUTIL /r enn /L[path to log files] /s[path to checkpoint file] /d[path to database file] /i

Example: ESEUTIL /r e01 /Lf:\mdbdata /sc:\exchsrvr\mdbdata /dg:\mdbdata /i

These are all the available switches, so look at the article and use only what you need.

Edit:  Actually, the easiest way to accomplish this would be to just mount the database.  You can specify the log file location under the Properties of the Recovery Storage Group in Exchange System Manager.  Log file path points to logs (obviously), and System path is where the checkpoint file is located (you can just point it to the same place as where your logs are; this is the default location usually)

Comment: Is the checkpoint the env file?

Comment: The checkpoint file is .chk

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to let me change the Recovery Storage group properties.  It says the log files are R00 prefix which is not the case for me ...

Comment: I seem to lack a .chk file from the restore I did ...

Comment: The lack of a checkpoint file is not a show-stopper.  It just means that the when the EDB is mounted, it will have to roll in all the logs in.  I would check with your Exchange Admin, or look at the live EDB if you have access to see if the .chk file is in a different location than the logs.  I think the R00 prefix is the default if you didn't specify anything when you created the RSG.  What you could do is delete the RSG you have, then create a new one that points to all the componensts (EDB, STM, logs), and see if that works.

Comment: When I run the eseutil option I get a -528 Jet_errMissingLogFile error...

Comment: Also, `eseutil.exe I:\Logs\Company\e00` says all the log files are just grand.

Comment: dump the header of the logs and make sure that you have a consistent and unbroken log chain.  ESEUTIL /ML Exx, where xx is the prefix number.  References : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296788 and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997818(EXCHG.65).aspx

Comment: I'm starting to think that there is something else going on here that we're missing...

Answer (score 0):

When you run this command ESEUTIL /MH <database_name>

It shows the result that which log files are required.

The .Log files are named as the combination of log prefix and the Hexadecimal value.

The log prefix for any database is "E01"

For soft recovery, the log files beginning with E01 and ending with Hexadecimal value that are showing after running eseutil/mh command.

I have found step by step tutorial on Eseutil, here you can easily check how to Specify the location of the Exchange Logs for a eseutil Soft Recovery:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJieFultgJE&t=3s